# how can i get a part of string from xml in batch file

Tags: xml, batch-file, cmd, command-line, token

First, I'm reallly beginner at batch or cmd syntax.
So my syntax looks very foolish, please read this with a broad mind. Thx!

I want to get a value from my specific local xml file and i want to get a part of that value. Because, I have to compare with that value and specific other value.

well, I found it with all my effort. But I couldn't 100%.
Please read this code.

```
fc /b "C:\e\e.xml" "C:\Users\%username%\Documents\e\e.xml" return errorlevel

set usr_name=%username:~-2,2%
set _name=

IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (         
    for /f "tokens=2delims=<>" %%i in ('find "KEY" "c:\e\e.xml"') do echo %%i
    REM echo ^<username^>%usr_name%^</Setup_Date^>^<substr^>%%i^</substr^> > "C:\e\test.xml"    
            
    echo ^<username^>%usr_name%^</username^>^<substr^>%_name%^</substr^> > "C:\e\test.xml"
    if %%i:~-4,2 == %usr_name% (
    
    REM echo ^<username^>%usr_name%^</username^>^<substr^>%%i:~-4,2%^</substr^> > "C:\e\test.xml"
    echo YES
    ELSE (
echo NO
cscript no.vbs  
)
```

---

And this is my xml file.
I want to get D4 of KEY tag (D4, It occupies 2 letters from the 4th from the back.)

```
<Date>2020-08-13</Date><Setup>Zs#ol9fEV9pA</Setup>
<KEY>WY(T5XD4h4<KEY>
```

---

the problem is this

```
REM echo ^<username^>%usr_name%^</Setup_Date^>^<substr^>%%i^</substr^> > "C:\e\test.xml"    
            
echo ^<username^>%usr_name%^</username^>^<substr^>%_name%^</substr^> > "C:\e\test.xml"
```

if value i = abcdef
I can get the value from xml file abcdef, using REM sentence.
But I can't get the part of variable i.

when i use second sentence or other expressions such as %i:~-4,2% etc. (because i want to compare using that part of value. %i:~-4,2% = cd)
I can't print any values, just print nothing.

Is there a way to solve this problem?
As i said earlier, I have a very tiny knowledge about batch,
So let me know everything you know. Or if this way couldn't solve without using other library or xpath.bat, please tell me as I have to find another way.

Thank you.

Comment: Does it *have* to be a batch file? Could it also be VBScript? Or PowerShell? (Doing this correctly with on-board tools in batch is needlessly hard, and I would advise using something else, if at all possible.)

Comment: Also, include the XML (or a condensed sample of it) and point out exactly which parts you want to extract.

Comment: @Tomalak added my xml format. And I prefer VBScript, and if possible I've never thought about powershell, but it looks good. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Then let's do VBScript, since you already seem to be using it. Please add more of the XML - a complete file, not just two elements, but you can remove repetitive parts as long as the file still works afterwards.

Comment: @Tomalak oh.. well, that's all my xml file content. I just made a really simple file for checking. Do i have to add more tags  complicated?

Comment: If that's the entire file then that's not an XML file, that's a text file with some `<` and `>` sprinkled around. You need to make it well-formed XML first (check if Internet Explorer opens it without an error), or maybe use a different format than XML altogether, for example CSV.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, you're right. I just want to get value so i made a very simple tag. Thanks I think I'll find another file format or make a real xml format and use VBScript Thanks for reply

Comment: It can be simple, there is no problem with that. But what you are showing here *is not XML*. And until you either turn it into XML (it's missing a top-level element) or decide to use a less restrictive file format there is no way to move this question forward.

Answer (score 1):

`%%i` is only defined inside the `for` loop. As you wrote it, the whole loop consists of only `echo %%i`. Then the loop ends and `%%i` isn't defined anymore.

As others already noted, `cmd` isn't really a good tool to work with when it comes to XML files (and look-alikes).

But if you are willing to use an [external tool](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044), it gets easy. Just a simple REGEX search for a string between `<KEY>` and `<KEY>` (shouldn't the second be `</KEY>`?):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('^<"c:\e\e.xml jrepl ".*<KEY>(.*)<KEY>.*" "$1" /a') do set "key=%%a"
echo Key: %key%, Subkey:%key:~-4,2%
```

`jrepl.bat` was programmed by [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053/dbenham).